# Probability mass function similarity

Tags: probability, dice, card-games

Consider this:

Five cards are individually drawn from a shuffled 52-card deck. The corresponding probability space is (Ω, **F**, ℙ). Define a random variable $X$: Ω → ℝ, which has the same probability mass function $f$, as the random variable representing the value of a single roll of a dice. I.e. $f(x)$ = ℙ{$X = x$} = 1/6, when $x$ ∈ {1,2,...,6}.

As a hint: 48 is divided by 6, and if we have a fixed a set of 48 cards, then at least one of them is included in a set of five cards.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Use `\{1,2,\dots,6\}` for denoting sets.

Comment: Have you learnt from your mistakes which caused [your suspension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xetqr.png)?

Comment: I see you answered this question within the follow-up question. But you might also post that as an answer to this question in the answer section below, and also accept it so that it is clear you don't still need an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As a fair die has the same chance of showing each face, you are asked to come up with a strategy that takes the set of five card draws from a standard pack and produces a random number from $1$ to $6$ with all numbers equally probable.  If we were given five flips of a coin we would note that there are $32$ possible results of flipping a coin five times.  We would choose five of those to represent $1$, five to represent $2$ and so on.  We would have two left over and if we got one of those we would have to flip again.

There are $52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48=311875200$ ordered five card draws from a deck.  As this is divisible by $6$ you can separate them into six equal groups and always have a result of a number $1$ to $6$.  The hint suggests one way that is easier to remember than others.

Comment: [slightly off topic] I have in mind one way to use the hint, which is indeed easy to describe/remember, but it uses the ORDER of the draw.  However, since 311875200 / (5!) is still divisible by 6, there are ways to do this without using the order of the draw (i.e. where the random variable gives the same value for a 5-card hand regardless of order of draw).  But I cannot think of an "easy to describe" way.  Any idea / hint?

Comment: You were intended to use the order, I believe

Comment: of course, I understand.  I'm just saying: if the order is used, the problem is not hard.  But if the order is _not_ used, the problem is still solvable BUT I cannot think of an _easy_ answer (which therefore makes for a nice little puzzle by itself -- how simple can we make the solution if order cannot be used?)

Comment: Here is a simple one:   Ignore any Kings you draw.  Counting Aces as 1, Jacks as 11, Queens as 12, add the other ranks $\bmod 6$

Comment: You're drawing without replacement.  So once you draw a 3 mod 6, your next draw is less likely to be a 3 mod 6.  Thought experiment: let Red = 0, Black = 1.  Draw 2 cards without replacement.  Probability that sum is odd = 26/51...  And if symmetry is broken in this thought experiment, I dont see how it is preserved in the mod 6 case.

Comment: You are right.  Here is a less simple one.  Again ignore kings (until the end).  If you have distinct ranks, add them $\bmod 6$.  If you have at least one pair, take the rank with maximum quantity $\bmod 6$.  This handles all draws except xxyyz and Kxxyy.  For the first, take $z \bmod 6$.  For the second, if the king is red take the higher rank of $x$ or $y$, if the king is black take the lower.

Comment: I like your direct, fix-what's-broken style.  :D  BTW a very _very_ slight simplification is for both xxyyz and Kxxyy, take (x+y) mod 6.  Thanks!

Comment: After thinking for a few hours, I no longer think your latest solution works.  I have started a new post on the modified question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752657/simulating-a-fair-die-with-a-5-card-hand - thanks for your interesting thoughts so far and you'd be most welcome to continue discussing in the new thread

Comment: In the original problem its says "cards are drawn one-by-one", so assumably they are drawn in order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still can't figure out how to reach the solution. I.e. what is the random variable for the draw of five cards, so that f(x) = ℙ{X=x} = 1/6, when x ∈ {1,2,...,6} ?

Comment: @antkam:  My approach in the last comment works if you take the ranks $\bmod 6$ before looking for pairs.  Taking the sum is then the same as adding $3$ to the missing rank because the ranks sum to $3 \bmod 6$

Comment: @HaydenSpetting:  antkam's question has a couple answers that achieve that.  My approach of adding the ranks may not quite work as s/he points out.

Comment: @RossMillikan taking the ranks mod6 makes the case of 5 different ranks uniform.  But the problem of KKKxy remains, since x+y is more likely to be odd than even.  (I.e. assuming I understand you correctly)  I'm a "he" BTW.  Nice to meet you.  :)